# Azure SQL Restore Failed - Status Conflict (Details show Internal Server Error)

Tags: azure-sql-database, restore, azureportal

I am restoring to a point in time, as a BCP test and it has failed.  This is being done in the portal to a new database name that does not exist.  It is not in an elastic pool.  It tries to deploy and the new database shows up in SQL Management Studio as restoring.  It then disappears and the portal shows as failed after running for a couple of hours on a DB of a few hundred MB.

I have tried another db and the same issue is present.  They are all DTU based.

The statis is shown as conflict, and the detailed error is shown as Internal Server Error.

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

I created database in Azure portal and click on the restore at overview of database

Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

I click on the Review+Create button I got the same error
as you got

Image for reference:

[image]

I repeated the steps for restore the database which I have done above and changing time the database is restored successfully.

Image for reference:
[image]

Restored database:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer here, but it is only really confirming it's broken.  The point of a specific time is because of a data disaster and you need to restore to a precise point.  I thankfully don't, but it still fails our entire BCP test if you can't.  What happens if someone accidentally delete everything?  If this was a disaster we would have a major issue and sounds like many others will be and are just unaware because they don't do BCP tests.